# How to use a static method as a callback in c++

Tags: c++, oop, functional-programming, c++17, c++14

I have a comparison/ordering function that relates to a class. I can use it if I define it as a separate closure object. I would like to make it into a static method of the class it operates on so it is tidier. I guessed how to do this but I get an error that I can't interpret.

Generally I would like to know how to treat static methods as callable objects.

Minimal related example code (not working):

```
#include <set>

class MyClass {

    // More code here

    static auto compare(MyClass a, MyClass b)   {
        return a < b;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::set<MyClass, decltype(MyClass::compare)> s(MyClass::compare);
    return 0;
}
```

Update, I'm not sure if my example confused the issue, so I updated it.

Comment: `&MyClass::compare`

Comment: Note: C++17 allows you to write `auto s = std::set(&MyClass::compare);` thanks to CTAD. However I'd consider the following tidier than your option: `struct MyCompare { bool operator()(int a, int b) const { return a < b; } };` `auto s = std::set(MyCompare());` or pre C++17 `std::set<int, MyCompare> s = MyCompare();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues:

- `compare` is private, make it public.
- One must use `&` to get the address of functions.

```
#include <set>

class MyClass {
public:
    static auto compare(int a, int b)   {
        return a < b;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::set<int, decltype(&MyClass::compare)> s(&MyClass::compare);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The & seems not to be required in the second MyClass::compare (but it still works with it)

Comment: @user83455 Yes, it is not necessary but I consider it good practice. Free or static member functions decay to pointers but member methods won't and `&` would be necessary for them, not that a method would be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Make the function `public`, and add `&` in `decltype`:

```
std::set<int, decltype(&MyClass::compare)>
```

I wouldn't consider this to be "tidier" though.

A functor occupies 0 bytes when used as a `std::set` comparator. But a function pointer (as in your example) occupies 4 or 8 bytes. It also forces you to pass the function to the set's constructor.

Using a function pointer this way only makes sense if you want to switch between different comparators at runtime.

If you do want a pointer, the class itself is unnecessary. You might as well use a free function.

Comment: And, if you really want to encapsulate the comparator function, don't use a class, use a namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the extra advice. I take it your comment about bytes regards inlining? A closure object can be inlined (or maybe an equivalent optimisation being copy elided?) but a pointer to a method will not?

Regarding "tidier", I appreciate there is no runtime difference by writing the subroutine as a method. It is based on my background from other languages, putting it lexically inside the class intends to make it clear it relates exclusively to the class / more difficult to be split up from it etc.

Comment: @Fureeish great, it sounds like a namespace is exactly what I need.

Comment: @user83455 It's not related to inlining (though a functor should be easier to inline, yes). It's just that `sizeof` of a (stateless) functor is 1 (and since it's [empty](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_empty), `std::set` will put it on top of its other members, making the size effectively 0), while `sizeof(&MyClass::compare)` is 4 or 8.

Comment: Thank you @HolyBlackCat . I don't really understand but I think that is my problem rather than anything about your answer. I moved my confusion to a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70226584/why-should-i-prefer-a-separate-function-over-a-static-method-for-functional-prog so it can allow a proper answer. I guess it is that one version is compile time / type related (zero size) and the other is runtime / pointer related maybe.