# Why should I prefer a separate function over a static method for functional programming in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, functional-programming, c++17, c++14

In my other question, [How to use a static method as a callback in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70225854/how-to-use-a-static-method-as-a-callback-in-c), people solved my practical problem, then suggested I take a different approach in general to follow best practice. I would like a better understanding of why.

This example uses a comparator, but I would really like to understand if there is a general rule for functional programming (for example perhaps also aggregator functions related to a class etc.)

Example use case for a comparator function:

```
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::set<MyClass, decltype(SOMETHING_HERE)> s(SOMETHING_HERE);
    return 0;
}
```

Below are solutions I am aware of, from most to least recommended (I believe) - the opposite order to what I would currently choose.

#### 1.

Recommended way (I believe) with a functor:

```
struct MyComparator {
    bool operator() (MyClass a, MyClass b) const {
        return a > b; // Reversed
    }
};
```

```
std::set<MyClass, MyComparator)> s;
```

I don't like: verbose; not lexically tied to MyClass; I don't understand why s has no constructor argument. I am confused about the lack of argument because `set` seems to mix up/combine deciding the comparison algorithm at compile time / with the typesystem (as in this example), and at runtime / with a pointer. If it was just one way or the other I would be fine with "that's just how it is".

#### 2.

A method that seems nicer to me:

```
auto const my_comparator = [](int a, int b) {
    return a > b;
};
```

```
std::set<int, decltype(my_comparator)> s(my_comparator);
```

It's terser. Intention is clear: it is a function, not a class that could be potentially added to. Passing the object, not just the type, makes sense to me (couldn't there be 2 different implementations).

#### 3.

The method that makes most sense to me (based on other languages):

```
class MyClass {
public:
    
    // More code here
    
    static auto compare_reverse(MyClass a, MyClass b) {
        return a > b;
    }
};
```

```
std::set<int, decltype(&MyClass::compare_reverse)> s(&MyClass::compare_reverse);
```

It is clearly related (and lexically tied to) MyClass. Seems efficient (though I have been told it's not) and terse.

---

Any explanation why the recommended order is better, performance, bugs/maintainability, philosophical, very appreciated.

Comment: For the problem of ordering for `std::set` or `std::map` (or default ordering for `std::sort` and other functions), why not create a `bool MyClass::operator<(MyClass const&)` function?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude there already is one. It has many orderings. Thank you for highlighting that aspect.

Comment: `decltype(MyComparator())` is simply `MyComparator`. You are making it more verbose than it needs to be. As to "lexically tied" - you can make `MyComparator` a nested class in `MyClass`, and refer to it as `MyClass::MyComparator`. And if for some reason you feel better passing a constructor argument, you can pass `MyComparator{}` (though I must admit I don't understand how one can complain about "too verbose" and "not verbose enough" in the span of one sentence).

Comment: Wait. So `std::set<MyClass, MyComparator)> s;` is too verbose, while `std::set<int, decltype(my_comparator)> s(my_comparator);` is terser? By what measure of verbosity? Clearly not by number of characters. What goal function are you trying to optimize?

Comment: @user83455: "*It's terser.*" No, it isn't. #2 clearly requires more text at the variable definition site than #1. It also creates a global variable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik My concern with missing the constructor argument is not one of terseness. It is the separate issue that I just don't understand why it is needed sometimes and not others. My understanding (maybe incorrect) is decltype is type system related / compile time, but the pointer is runtime. I would expect one or other method of determining the implementation in a given programming language, but not both. My concern is if `set` can vary at runtime, how can it work without information at runtime? (maybe c++ is just way cooler than I thought).

Comment: @NicolBolas That's fair, but I don't understand why one form needs an argument and the other doesn't and I would like to know that. For example if I could combine the closure definition with the argument-free form (or perhaps omit the decltype) that would be ideal. I don't see the distinction between a const global function variable and a class. Coming from a lispy background they seem roughly equivalent. I guess the type system can do cooler stuff with the class?

Comment: `std::set<T, Comp>` default-constructs `Comp` if an instance of `Comp` is not passed to the constructor. That's all there is to it. While uncommon, a comparator may be  stateful and may have constructors with parameters - then an instance would have to be constructed explicitly and passed to the `set`. Imagine e.g. a set of pointers into some external data structure, where you compare pointers by looking up actual values they point to, and comparing those. The comparator may take a reference to that external data structure in its constructor.

Comment: "`my_comparator` is a function, not a class" . That's technically incorrect. `my_comparator` is an object of some class type (that cannot be named other than via `decltype(my_comparator)`). A lambda expression is a shorthand for writing a class with `operator()`. Starting with C++20 you could even omit the constructor argument, as in `std::set<int, decltype(my_comparator)> s;`, since captureless lambdas have been made default-constructible.

Comment: Using a plain C function pointer as a comparator is likely to preclude inlining, which may hurt performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, note that if you just want a `>` comparator, there are [`std::greater<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) and `std::greater<MyClass>` ([the former is usually superior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators)).

---

Reviewing the options you listed:

**(1)**

```
struct MyComparator
{
    bool operator()(MyClass a, MyClass b) const
    {
        return a > b;
    }
};
std::set<MyClass, MyComparator)> s;
```

As you said, this is the recommended way.

> not lexically tied to MyClass

As suggested in the comments, you can put it inside `MyClass`.

> don't understand why s has no constructor argument

If you don't pass the comparator to the constructor, the comparator is default-constructed (if it's default-constructible, otherwise you get a compilation error).

You can pass `MyComparator{}` manually, but there is no point.

**(2)**

```
auto my_comparator = [](int a, int b)
{
    return a > b;
};
std::set<int, decltype(my_comparator)> s(my_comparator);
```

It's exactly equivalent to (1), except you're forced to pass `my_comparator` to the constructor. C++20 fixed this by making lambdas default-constructible (if they have no captures), making the argument unnecessary.

**(3)**

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
    static auto compare_reverse(MyClass a, MyClass b)
    {
        return a > b;
    }
};
std::set<int, decltype(&MyClass::compare_reverse)> s(&MyClass::compare_reverse);
```

This gives you an extra feature: you can choose the comparator at runtime, by passing different functions to the constructor.

This ability comes with an overhead: the set stores a pointer to the function (normally 4 or 8 bytes), and has to look at the pointer when making comparisons.

**(3.5)**

You can wrap your function in [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant). The result is equivalent to (1).

```
bool foo(int x, int y) {return x > y;}

std::set<int, std::integral_constant<decltype(&foo), foo>> s;
// Or:
using MyComparator = std::integral_constant<decltype(&foo), foo>;
std::set<int, MyComparator> s;
```

This is good if you're dealing with an existing type, that provides the comparator as a function, and you don't want the overhead of (3).

---

All of those (except (3)) are equivalent.

If `std::greater<>` is applicable, you should use it.

Otherwise I'd recommend (1) as the least confusing option.

Comment: Thank you, amazing answer! I've learned a ton.

Comment: Don't forget [`std::ranges::greater`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ranges/greater)!